# Upgrading Mac mini (Mid 2011) RAM

Tags: hardware, upgrade, memory, mac-mini

I've got a Mac mini (Mid 2011). It currently has 4 GB of RAM which I want to upgrade to 16 GB. I know that officially with these versions, only 8 GB is supported, but I've read from [OWC Announces Industry’s First 16 GB RAM Upgrade For Latest Apple Mac Mini Models](http://blog.macsales.com/11292-owc-announces-industrys-first-16gb-ram-upgrade-for-latest-apple-mac-mini-models) that you can actually upgrade to 16 GB.

I've found this memory, [Corsair CMSX16GX3M2B1600C9 Vengeance 16GB (2 x 8GB) 1600Mhz DDR3L 9-9-9-24 204pin 1.35V Notebook Memory](http://www.wootware.co.za/corsair-cmsx16gx3m2b1600c9-vengeance-16gb-2-x-8gb-1600mhz-ddr3l-9-9-9-24-204pin-1-35v-notebook-memory.html), which I want to upgrade to. My concern is that it's 1600 MHz and that my Mac mini comes with 1333 MHz memory.

How can I understand what Mac memory requirements are so I can select the proper parts to expand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this site [here](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/mac-mini-aluminum-unibody-faq/how-to-upgrade-ram-memory-aluminum-unibody-mac-mini.html).
It appears that your mac can only use the 1333mhz ram sticks, the 2012 models can work with the faster memory.
The site also states that 16gb is not suported **but** unofficial it will work anyway.

In [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48622/71490) answer a similar question is answered, *if* it works it wil run at 1333mhz since your ram slots can't go any faster.

But since macs are really picky about the memory you use there is a big chance it won't work at all.

Comment: Thanks. But I wonder if the 1600mhz sticks will work anyway, or if it'll just bomb out?

Comment: @orrymr, While in many cases using a higher frequency is okay, as it will only run at the frequency of the FSB anyway, nonetheless some Apple motherboards will not work properly with a higher frequency then what was shipped.  So, I'd opt for finding RAM that match the manufacture's specifications, especially when doubling the amount specified by Apple as it maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The correct RAM to use is SODIMM DDR3 with 1.5V as voltage and 1333MHz as clock speed.

Ensure the latency is CL9 and remember that your Mac mini supports a maximum of 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

Corsair Mac memory 8GB DDR3L-1600MHz, 204-pin SODIMM (CMSA8GX3M1A1600C11)
I had 2 of this in my mac mini 2011 server,  and run perfectly for 6 months , but now one memory has gone bad
Still runs, finds no error in mem test, but mac reboots from time to time... the other 8 is fine so i have just 8 now till decide what to get